# Getting Object out of string

Tags: javascript

I am getting an object by name response, which has a property by name attribute.

On hovering on

```
response.attribute
```

I see

```
"{"Coupon Circle":"coupon_circle"}"
```

in chrome developer tools.(see Image)

[image]

On doing below

```
JSON.parse(response.attributes);
```

I get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

What should I do in order to get the object out of it?

Comment: There is mistake in your string. You may want to try this... http://jsfiddle.net/a2cLjmy6/1/

Comment: I am getting an object where I get value like this
attributes: "{"XYZ Circle":"xyz_circle"}"

Answer (score 0):

**Use `JSON.parse()`.**

The string is a json-object, which can be converted to an object with JavaScripts native [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp) parser. Pass the string to `JSON.parse()` and it will give you the object.

Comment: This question has been asked / answered hundreds of times... please don't encourage people asking again and again.

Comment: I have edited my question, please take a look